# Can not apply second incremental backup file using xtrabackup

Tags: percona

I am trying to follow the steps mentioned on this page:

https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/LATEST/backup_scenarios/incremental_backup.html

I have successfully managed to apply logs from inc1 folder. (i.e. /data3/backups/inc1)

```
bin/xtrabackup --prepare --apply-log-only --target-dir=/data3/backups/ --incremental-dir=/data3/backups/inc1
```

But the next incremental backup can not be applied because the previous command that applied inc1 backup, removed the checkpoints file from inc2 folder (which is very strange)

```
# bin/xtrabackup --prepare  --target-dir=/data3/backups/ --incremental-dir=/data3/backups/inc2
xtrabackup: Error: cannot open /data3/backups/inc2//xtrabackup_checkpoints
xtrabackup: error: failed to read metadata from /data3/backups/inc2//xtrabackup_checkpoints
```

How do I apply the second incremental file?

Comment: Those are the correct steps. After applying inc1, when you `ls /data3/backups/inc2/` you say the checkpoints file is gone? Can you verify that after taking the 2nd incremental that the checkpoints file exists? Can you also give the steps you took to create the backups?

Comment: Yes. checkpoints file exist but is gone after applying inc1 very strange but true. Here are the steps I followed: http://oksoft.blogspot.in/2017/12/using-xtra-backup-for-incremental.html

Comment: I had no issues following the steps in your blog post. My output: https://ghostbin.com/paste/sgne7 I used sysbench to simulate some data changes. Took a full. Ran SB. Took inc1. Ran DB. Took inc2. Restored everything. No issues. There's no code that could have removed the checkpoints file from a different directory. Can you confirm the file is present after you take inc2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that incremental directory can not be within the base directory. So this config is wrong:

```
--target-dir=/data3/backups/ --incremental-dir=/data3/backups/inc2
```

It should be ...

```
--target-dir=/data3/backups/full --incremental-dir=/data3/backups/inc2
```

In other words full and incremental directories should be visible like this...

```
# ls /data3/backups/
full  inc1  inc2
```

If inc1 and inc2 are within "full" sub-folder then you will have problems!